# Regex to match single, non-consecutive tabs in an arbitrary string?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string which could contain just about anything. I need to be able to select just the tabs (\t) that are not consecutive.

In the example below, \t is used in place of an actual tab for clarity.

Example string:

```
\t\t \t \t a\t
\ta\t\td
dd
d\t \t\t\t
```

In this case, the tabs represented with a capital \T would be the ones I would want to select, only:

```
\t\t \T \T a\T
\Ta\t\td
dd
d\T \t\t\t
```

So three on the first line, one on the second line, and one on the fourth line would be selected. All others would be ignored because they are consecutive tabs. Note that the last tab on the first line and the first tab on the second line are separated by a carriage return and/or new line character, so they do not count as consecutive.

I have been at this for hours and am not making progress. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative look arounds either side of a tab:

```
(?<!\t)\t(?!\t)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/85uoO1O2SaCYho).

`(?<!\t)` is a *negative look-behind* and means “the previous character must not be a tab”, which is true at the start of input too.

`(?!\t)` is a *negative look-ahead* and means “the following character must not be a tab”, which is true at the end of input too.

Look arounds assert, but don’t consume, the input.

Comment: Thanks a ton! PM me your address, will gladly send beer or your drink of choice.